# Spawning random objects but with one specific one

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit

I got my game where I have four lanes going upwards from the bottom of my screen to the top. I got a object which is the right one showing on my scene and I spawn random objects in a spawn wave, 1 for each lane, so 4 at a time, and I want to check that at least one of the 4 objects is the right object, if not, delete and spawn new 4 objects until you got one right. 
Sometimes you have to wait like 10-20 seconds until a right object appears which is boring and takes you out of the game flow.

Following code spawns the helmets:

```
private func spawnRandomHelmet() {
    let helmet = HelmetNode(fruit: .random())
    helmet.delegate = self
    helmet.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - helmet.size.height)
    addChild(helmet)

    let endOfFieldForHelmet = self.size.height * 0.7864 - (helmet.size.height - screenWidth / 7.5)
    let helmetOutOfScreen = self.size.height + helmet.size.height

    let moveHelmetUp = SKAction.moveTo(y: endOfFieldForHelmet, duration: self.config.helmetSpeed)
    helmet.run(moveHelmetUp) {
        let moveHelmetOutOfScreen = SKAction.moveTo(y: helmetOutOfScreen, duration: 0.5)
        let fadeOutHelmet = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5)
        let moveAndFadeOut = SKAction.group([moveHelmetOutOfScreen, fadeOutHelmet])
        helmet.run(moveAndFadeOut) {
            helmet.removeFromParent()
            self.delegate?.removed(helmet.fruit)
        }
    }
}
```

Following code is from HelmetNode.swift:

```
class HelmetNode: SKSpriteNode {
    weak var delegate: HelmetNodeDelegate?
    let fruit: Fruit

    init(fruit: Fruit) {
        self.fruit = fruit
        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "helmet \(fruit.name)")
        let size = CGSize(width: laneWidth, height: screenWidth / 3)
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clear, size: size)
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        zPosition = 2
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    static func random(count: Int = 4) -> [HelmetNode] {
        var helmets: [HelmetNode] = []
        for _ in 1...count  {
            helmets.append(HelmetNode(fruit: .random()))
        }
        return helmets
    }
}
```

Following code is from Fruit.swift:

```
enum Fruit: Int {
    case grapes = 0
    case orange
    case pear
    case cherry
    case pineapple

    static var count: UInt32 = 5

    var name: String {
        switch self {
        case .grapes:
            return "grapes"
        case .cherry:
            return "cherry"
        case .orange:
            return "orange"
        case .pear:
            return "pear"
        case .pineapple:
            return "pineapple"
        }
    }

    static func random() -> Fruit {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(count))
        return Fruit(rawValue: randomNumber)!
    }
}
```

The right fruit is initialized in my GameScene.swift as `fruit`

Answer (score 0):

There is too many unknown variables to exactly tell you how to layout your code, such as what is in the HelemtNode code, what type is fruit (enum, class, struct), what is in your random() code.

So this is just a guideline of how to do this but it will have to be adapted to fit your code better.

```
//func used to create all 4 helmets
func spawnHelmets() {

    //find the correct type first
    let correctType = HelmetNode.random()

    //spawn the correct type
    spawnRandomHelmetOf(type: correctType)

    //spawn the remaining 3 but as types other than correct
    for x in 0...3 {
        let randomType = randomNotOf(type: correctType)
        spawnRandomHelmetOf(type: randomType )
    }
}

//recursive function to find random type NOT of a certain type
func randomNotOf(type: FruitType) -> FruitType {

    //you'll have to figure out your own random variables here these are unknown to me
    let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxTypes)))

    if random != type {
        //doesn't match the type so we can return it
        return random as! FruitType
    }
    else {
        //using recursion will run the loop until it finds a match that is not of the same type
        return randomNotOf(type: type)
    }
}

private func spawnRandomHelmetOf(type: FruitType) {

    let helmet = HelmetNode(fruit: type)
    helmet.delegate = self
    helmet.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0 - helmet.size.height)
    addChild(helmet)

    //add your positioning code
}
```

Comment: I added my code for HelmetNode, Fruit class and the random function. Would be kind if you give me more specific help since I'm really new with swift